# Win32 Enter while in textbox triggers ok button

Tags: c++, c, winapi, input, mfc

The title isn't very explicit but here is my problem :

I have a MFC-based application with a dialog that has :

- 1 Text input;
- 1 Ok button;
- 1 cancel button;
- 1 button with an arrow to type in the next value

When the text box has the focus, pushing enter triggers the OK button. Why ? The text box has the focus, not the OK button so why would it do that ?

What i need ito to redirect the enter key to the arrow button instead of the ok button so that pushing enter doesn't close the dialog but goes to the next input.

Why can i do that please ? If i use SetFocus on the arrow button, the text box loses the focus, as expected, and this is not what i want.

Answer (score 3):

You must set the `Multiline` and the `Want Return` properties of your edit control to `True`.

Answer (score 2):

If an edit control does not have the style `ES_WANTRETURN` pressing `ENTER` has the same effect as pushing the dialog's default button. However, this style has no effect on single line controls, so you must also set the `ES_MULTILINE` style for the control.